# Why you can delete your questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Deleting your questions only ban you from asking questions, so why you can delete your questions at all if it is **not** helpful at all?

Comment: Why **not** allow people to delete questions? (not sure - are you *trying* to get into a question ban here on Meta? It is very hard to do, but not impossible).

Comment: I just do**n't** see the profit of deleting questions. That's all. I do understand why you can delete answers and comments.

Comment: _It is very hard to do_ is the criteria is different for MSE @Oded?

Comment: @i-- I do**n't** understand your comment.

Comment: @i-- - the thresholds have been vastly relaxed here, given we _want_ to hear people (dissenting views and all)/

Comment: So, you don't see the value of someone deleting their own off-topic questions as soon as they realise they posted on the wrong site, @Erez?

Comment: I assume that they did post on the right site, but the question itself is just bad.

Comment: What if the OP doesn't know how to improve the question, but realises it is bad? What do you expect them to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We want people to delete their bad questions.

We also don't want them to delete *all* their questions (assuming there are some good ones in the mix).

We want to discourage people from asking a lot of bad questions (low quality/off-topic/too broad/duplicate - choose your poison), just to delete them.

---

What will get someone into a question ban is consistent bad asking over time. Deleting one bad post - that's fine, so long as there are good ones to offset it.

Comment: But bad questions should be improved, not to be deleted, because that wo**n't** lift the question ban.

Comment: Not all questions *can* be improved. How would you improve a question about carburetors here?

Comment: Then shall I ask a new question: "What to do if I am question and answer banned and all my bad questions ca**n't** be improved?"?

Comment: you will get a chance after a certain period. I think 6 month. If you added a well recieved post, the ban will be lifted

Comment: Can you cut it out with the **n't** bolding? It is annoying and unnecessary. Who does that?

Comment: Also - @Erez - **look up that new question**. It might (!) have already been asked.

Comment: Why didn't you link me to that new question then?

Comment: Wow. I'm supposed to do **everything** for you? There's a search box at the top of the page, @ErezZrihen - use it.

Comment: @ErezZrihen - Oded means, you should see if your question has already been asked, on the SE website in question.  Considering we don't actually know your question, and that isn't an invitation to actually tell us your question in a comment, we couldn't provide a link to said question even if we wanted to.

Comment: ["Deleted posts are mostly irrelevant to the question ban..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)

Comment: A side note you cant delete a bad question if an upvoted answer exist. On really bad question its hard to not take it personnally as you cant mute the question feedback nor simply delete it.